# React Router — How to include a navigation bar on every page plus NavLink activeClass

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
  <Router history={history}>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
          <PublicRoute exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/>

          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
  </Router>
```

This works fine when using Link but when i try to use NavLink it doesnt add activeClass because, i guess, < Navbar /> is outside of the Switch and therefore it doesnt have location prop. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As a child of the `Router` component, I would have expected a prop such as location or history on the Navbar - I would check again to see what props are available on Navbar related to navigation. Otherwise, perhaps you can pass the `history` object to the `Navbar` component, in the same way you pass it to the `Router` component?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, i just wrote `<Navbar />` inside the `<Route />` like everything else, like this

```
<Route path='/' component={Navbar}/>
```